# Combine 2 codes with loops into 1 single code

Tags: excel, vba

After various trial and errors and helps from this forum, I managed to come out with the following codes to achieve what I want but it's two vba loops. I am hit with bottleneck on how to combine these two vba with loops into 1 single vba.
Here is my code.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'


Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer


WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


For I = 1 To WS_Count


Sheets(I).Select 

Range("B11").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("B11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Outlet name"
Range("C11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PO Number"
Range("D11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PO Date"
Range("E11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Delivery Date"



' Copy outlet name
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A12").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'   Copy PO number
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A12").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'   Copy PO date
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A12").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'   Copy DO date
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A12").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste



Next I
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Here is the second vba.

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub Marco2()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

Last = LastRow(DestSh)


Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A12").Offset(1).CurrentRegion
Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0)
Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1)
CopyRng.Copy

'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
GoTo ExitTheSub
End If


CopyRng.Copy
With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your valuable time to read through this.

Cheers

Comment: Can't you call both subs in separate sub?

Comment: Do you run `Macro1`, followed by `Marco2`, or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Without explanation, it's unclear what this code is supposed to do, but I cleaned it up a little bit anyhow.

Create a separate procedure to run these two sub's in whichever order you need them to run.  For example:

```
Sub runMyThings()
    Call Macro1
    Call Macro2
End Sub
```

Note that I changed the name of `Marco2` to `Macro2`, but you should probably give them more meaningful names than that.  (Otherwise it's like having all your files called `File`.)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Range("B11").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Range("B11").FormulaR1C1 = "Outlet name"
        Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Number"
        Range("D11").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Date"
        Range("E11").FormulaR1C1 = "Delivery Date"

        ' Copy outlet name
        Range("B1").Copy
        Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Paste

        '   Copy PO number
        Range("B2").Copy
        Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Paste

        '   Copy PO date
        Range("B3").Copy
        Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Paste

        '   Copy DO date
        Range("B4").Copy
        Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Paste
    Next i

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub Macro2()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next 'this will delete the Sheet WITHOUT WARNING.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A12").Offset(1).CurrentRegion
            Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0)
            Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1)
            CopyRng.Copy

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not proud of leaving the code like this but without a better idea of what you're trying to do, I can't do anything more.  (And if it doesn't work now, revert to your previous code.)

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to refactor your code some to eliminate most of the select statements and combine various offsets and endup's and enddown's. (You should check that the combined results are still what you expect.)

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count  'ThisWorkbook (?)

    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        with Sheets(I)
            .Range(.Range("B11"), .Range("B11").End(xlDown).Offset(0,4)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Range("B11").FormulaR1C1 = "Outlet name"
            .Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Number"
            .Range("D11").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Date"
            .Range("E11").FormulaR1C1 = "Delivery Date"

            ' Copy outlet name
            .Range("B1").Copy
            .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 1).End(xlUp)).Paste

            '   Copy PO number
            .Range("B2").Copy
            .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 2).End(xlUp)).Paste

            '   Copy PO date
            .Range("B3").Copy
            .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 3).End(xlUp)).Paste

            '   Copy DO date
            .Range("B4").Copy
            .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 4).End(xlUp)).Paste
        end with
    Next I
End Sub
```

I added some commentary to the following sub as well:

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub Marco2()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    'If the sheet is always being deleted from the workbook which holds this code, the following line should be:

    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete

    'That way, if multiple books are open, it won't try to delete from the wrong workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add  'ThisWorkbook (?)
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    'ThisWorkbook (?)
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A12").Offset(1).CurrentRegion
            Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1)
            CopyRng.Copy

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            CopyRng.Copy

            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

            End If
        Next sh 'added sh to be more explicit on which loop this is for

ExitTheSub:

        Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

        'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
        DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
End Sub
```

**Answer**
I noticed that both subs loop through the worksheets in the workbook, so you should be able to combine the two by taking the code from within one sheet-loop and inserting it into the other, like so:

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub Marco2()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    'If the sheet is always being deleted from the workbook which holds this code, the following line should be:

    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete

    'That way, if multiple books are open, it won't try to delete from the wrong workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add  'ThisWorkbook (?)
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    'ThisWorkbook (?)

    -------------------------------------------------------------
    |   'From Macro1
    |   with sh
    |       .Range(.Range("B11"), .Range("B11").End(xlDown).Offset(0,4)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    |       .Range("B11").FormulaR1C1 = "Outlet name"
    |       .Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Number"
    |       .Range("D11").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Date"
    |       .Range("E11").FormulaR1C1 = "Delivery Date"
    |
    |       ' Copy outlet name
    |       .Range("B1").Copy
    |       .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 1).End(xlUp)).Paste
    |       
    |       '   Copy PO number
    |       .Range("B2").Copy
    |       .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 2).End(xlUp)).Paste
    |       
    |       '   Copy PO date
    |       .Range("B3").Copy
    |       .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 3).End(xlUp)).Paste
    |
    |       '   Copy DO date
    |       .Range("B4").Copy
    |       .Range(.Range("A12").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4), .Range("A12").Offset(1, 4).End(xlUp)).Paste
    |   End With
    |   'End of from Macro1
    ----------------------------------------------------------

        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A12").Offset(1).CurrentRegion
            Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1)
            CopyRng.Copy

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            CopyRng.Copy

            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

            End If
        Next sh 'added sh to be more explicit on which loop this is for

ExitTheSub:

        Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

        'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
        DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
End Sub
```